# Legislation or Constitutional Amendment needed to prevent Government Shutdowns in the US?

Tags: united-states, budget, government-shutdown, funding

If we wanted to create a rule for the government budget that said that would prevent government from NOT leaving the government funded, would it require a constitutional amendment or could/should this be done by an appropriations law requiring only a majority of legislators?

Here's an example of what the wording might be like (not very formal, but I hope you get the idea of what I mean):

> If the House of Representatives or Senate fail to agree on new funding
>   or the Executive Branch fails to approve a budget, then the previous
>   funding shall stay in effect until a new one is agreed on.  The
>   government or no portion of it may be shut down without funding as a
>   result of the expiration of a budgeting law.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramm%E2%80%93Rudman%E2%80%93Hollings_Balanced_Budget_Act and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowsher_v._Synar strongly suggest you'd need a Constitutional amendment. You can't force a budget on tomorrow's Congress or today/tomorrow's President via law, since this power is embedded  in the Constitution. It's essentially the same reason we'd need a Balanced Budget amendment, not law.

Comment: But when we change congresses/presidents, we are already forcing a previously passed budget onto the new congress/president. It is also conceivable that since Congress appropriates, it would not be an infringement of its powers to decide how to continuously appropriate as in the Balanced Budget Law which would infringed on another branch of congress.

Comment: `when we change congresses/presidents, we are already forcing a previously passed budget onto the new congress/president`. No, we're not. There was a controversy a couple of years back re Congress not funding the enforcement of an existing law. And no, today's Congress can't infringe on the Constitutional right of future Congresses/Presidents. In fact, they can't even infringe on their **own** rights. If they pass such a law and change their mind later, they can do so.

Comment: Hi @barrycarter  Thanks for your feedback.  What I see happening is that the fiscal year overlaps the terms of congress and the president, so budgeting can occur that is enacted by one congress and continues into the next that would be elected with different members, thereby never having a say in that legislation.  That is what I mean.  Maybe I am just misunderstanding you.

Comment: As @daviid-s notes, the new Congress can't take back money that has already been spent, but once that money runs out, they are not legally required to appropriate any new money.

Comment: Random thought: this MAY explain why our deficit is so high. If Congress wants to appropriate $100M to something today, they can certainly do so. If they want to appropriate $10M a year for 10 years, they can certainly appropriate the first $10M, but there's no guarantee that future Congresses (or this Congress itself) will allocate $10M in future years.

Comment: @barrycarter As I read it, that was only found unconstitutional because certain powers were given to the comptroller general, which is a legislative rather than an executive office. And that involved someone making decisions on where the budget should be cut, rather than simply leaving a current budget in place.

Comment: @DM I think the issue here is that current budget has expired. Deciding to continue it at the same level of funding as previously (assuming there was even a way to do that) is not really the same as "leaving a current budget in place". Given that the budget is an explicit Constitutional duty of Congress, I doubt the Supreme Court would see "continuing the previous budget by default" as a decision that could be made without a Constitutional amendment. Of course, to put all this in perspective, the "shutdown" only really affects non-essential functions.

Comment: @barrycarter I'm really interested in stopping having shutdowns used for a political purpose, regardless if they affect a lot of people or not.  Other countries don't have this problem.

Comment: @barrycarter What about Social Security? It seems to have permanent statutory funding outside the budget, so why can't most other things work the same way if Congress should so choose? "For the purpose of enabling each State, as far as practicable under the conditions in such State, to furnish financial assistance to aged needy individuals, there is hereby authorized to be appropriated for each fiscal year a sum sufficient to carry out the purposes of this subchapter." https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/301

Comment: @DM Good question. As you know, the shutdown isn't complete. As https://www.newsweek.com/government-shutdown-social-security-disability-checks-1269131 (and several other sites) note: "Funding for the programs under Titles II, XVI, and XVIII of the Social Security Act will continue, even in the event of a lapse in appropriations". The question, of course, is why. It's possible the President and Congress have reached an agreement on the "essential services" portion of the budget, but I haven't researched this so far, and it would bizarrely suggest some form of line-item veto, hmmm

Comment: @barrycarter The Line-Item Veto Act of 1996 was found unconstitutional in 1998, so that's not it. It's my understanding that some appropriation bills were passed and some were not, leading to the partial shutdown. But SS appears to operate outside all of that; the payments would continue even if no new budget bills were passed (assuming the government still had enough people working to actually send the checks.)

Comment: @DM I ran out of room, but that's what I meant by "hmmm": it couldn't be a line-item veto, since that would require a Constitutional amendment. SS is primarily funded by the FICA (Federal Insurance Company of America) portion of payroll deductions, so you might be right, but it does use up other money as well. I think what you said about appropriation bills is correct: Congress can submit multiple budgets to the President and he/she can sign any of them that he/she chooses, but this still seems close to a line-item veto (perhaps it's a workaround to a literal line item veto).

Comment: Relevant: [History of the debt ceiling](https://www.npr.org/sections/money/2011/05/17/136363196/the-history-of-the-debt-ceiling)

Comment: @barrycarter FICA is the Federal Insurance Contributions Act.  There's no such thing as a Federal Insurance Company of America.

Comment: @barrycarter A bit late of a response, but to your first comments: A Congress can't force anything on future Congresses w/o an amendment, but they *can* change the default if that later Congress doesn't act.  The later Congress could change that default again, or pass a law so that the default isn't needed, but in either case, they're *actively* doing that.  Deadlock would fall back to the pre-defined default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Constitution, Congress has the power:

> To raise and support Armies, but no Appropriation of Money to that Use shall be for a longer Term than two Years;

So, without a constitutional amendment, there is no way to fund the military without passing at least a military spending resolution at least once every two years. But this also implies that for non-military spending, Congress has the power to pass a budget that lasts *more* than two years.

I think that Congress could, without a Constitutional amendment, specify that a previous budget would be in effect if no new budget was passed - at least for non-military spending. There's nothing in the Constitution to prevent it. However, you wouldn't want to do this for everything in the budget.

Let's say the budget one year contains $50 million to build a particular bridge in a particular location. If this provision kicked in, then another $50 million to build the same bridge would automatically be in the next year's budget. Are we going to build a second bridge in the same location? Or maybe there's $20 million to upgrade a particular agency's computer system. Are we going to upgrade it again? Probably not.

And things might become clouded when it comes to how the government is often funded - through continuing resolutions, instead of a budget. If a particular department gets $100 million per year in a budget, and they get $75 million for the first 9 months and then $30 million in a 3 month continuing resolution, how much should they get if this provision kicks in? $105 million, which is what they got in the last 12 months? $100 million, which was what they were allocated in the last actual budget? Or $120 million, which is the extrapolation of the last continuing resolution?

Congress could, of course, clear up any ambiguities by wording the laws correctly. And they could specify when an item was a one-off that shouldn't be automatically renewed. But they still might not want to pass this sort of law. Perhaps one reason is that it would be too easy to fall back on this, instead of passing a good budget that reflects the needs of the current year instead of the previous year.

Comment: "instead of passing a good budget that reflects the needs of the current year instead of the previous year" I'm not sure that's happened since 1793.

Comment: "I think that Congress could, without a Constitutional amendment, specify that a previous budget would be in effect if no new budget was passed" This fails in cases where Congress wants to change the budget (but not veto-proof majority) and the President does not. A President could just veto the spending bill and even though Congress wants to change the budget, they'd be impotent to do so.

Answer (score 3):

<s>**A normal vote is all that is needed.**</s>

**A constitutional amendment is needed to prevent it from being possible.**

The house originates the bill. It then goes to the Senate for changes/approval. Once the House and Senate have a bill to pass, they send it to the President to sign (bill is law) or veto (goes back). If it goes back then the bill requires a 2/3 majority to override the veto. To prevent it from happening, an amendment would be needed to alter how the separation of powers between legislative and executive function. That is, a clause needs to be added or altered. A law alone cannot circumvent a veto or required 2/3 override.

In this (current) case, it is the same as a veto. Two-thirds majority will overrule the veto and pass the budget. Additionally, the lack of the President's signature doesn't actually shut the government down, it only prevents it from spending more than what it is currently allowed to spend.

The shut down occurs when the various departments run out of money they were previously allocated.

Section 7 [here](https://constitutionus.com/).

To make changes that would prevent the government from ever shutting down would require amendments to the constitution. Specifically areas citing presidential approval or new language supporting a new mechanism to keep the budget operating.

To address your idea, this is already *somewhat* done in the sense that all essential federal government employees continue to work without pay. Once the budget is approved they will receive their back pay.

Edits to make improvements. Edit: To include information from comments

Comment: Hi @DavidS I'm not sure how this answers my question.  I just was asking how to require the government from not shutting down.  Can this be done through regular legislation or would it require a constitutional Amendment?  At the beginning, you say all you need is a normal vote and then you say a constitutional amendment?

Comment: I guess that is based on the context of your question. Are you asking what can be done in this instance? Or in general? The general answer is laid out in the link, it is explicitly said that it is done by vote to overrule a veto. Depending on how you are asking to "prevent' the shutdown will then change the answers.

Comment: In general.  I'm not interested in this specific case. Other countries never have this problem.  Specifically, I'm interested in not letting it happen again and preventing it through procedure/law/constitutional amendment.

Comment: A minor wrinkle as noted in Section 7: `All Bills for raising Revenue shall originate in the House of Representatives`. Of course, even if appropriations bills could be introduced by the Senate, the House could just vote against them, but this gives the House a little more indirect power re budgeting.

Comment: @barrycarter Unfortunately, many times appropriations bills are debated and created in the Senate before the House.  To keep it "constitutional", sometimes the House passes the Senate's version first even though the House didn't actually create them.

Comment: @Karlomanio Here the answer is still a constitutional amendment is needed to prevent it from being possible. 1 -> House creates bill, 2 -> Senate approves 3-> President sign (done) / veto -> goes back to reconsideration. To prevent it from happening, an amendment would be needed to alter how the separation of powers between legislative and executive function. That is, a clause needs to be added or altered. A law alone cannot circumvent a veto or required 2/3 override.

Comment: You are right @DavidS.  Put this comment as the answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @Karlomanio Technically, the Senate takes another bill from the House, amends it (which they can do) to replace the entire text with their bill to get around that "originate in the House" part.

Comment: @pboss3010 But once a bill is changed, it has to go back to the other chamber. So the Senate-revised/amended budget would then have to be re-approved by the House.

Answer (score 3):

Constitutional amendment.

I'm adding this answer because a lot of the existing commentary is getting lost in the weeds.

The fact is that any "mere legislation" that seeks to prevent government shutdowns indefinitely is subject to ongoing legislative review and repeal (think of the concept of the "nuclear option") in a way that the Constitution thankfully is not.

To be prudent the amendment may have to cover certain considerations and special cases that I haven't seen mentioned here but may already be a part of related law.  For example the expenditure should probably be indexed to inflation, GDP or other economic variables at the discretion of the executive to prevent unreasonable automatic budgeting under extraordinary economic conditions like hyperinflation.  Natural disaster or war may also justify certain kinds of opt out or automatic escalator clauses.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how far you want to go to "prevent".  No law could prevent a future Congress from undoing past law... Save a Constitutional Amendment. And even that is subject to ...further amendment. But:

The shutdown occurred because no funds were appropriated for certain purposes. I do not see why law could not be enacted authorizing and making appropriations to pay existing employees of the Civil Service etc under their existing employment contracts, rates of pay etc. and to pay for certain operations of the various departments (like buy gas for the FBI) - perhaps a long and carefully considered list - and to pay Military Salaries up to two years.... In other words appropriations language to make certain currently discretionary funds mandatory in the event of lack of discretionary funding.  Probably written in a way to let the Government limp without hurting its employees, soldiers and key beneficiaries etc, but still make regular appropriations necessary.

The laws establishing Mandatory Spending programs such as Social Security and Medicare make such ongoing appropriations.  I'm not aware of anything that says such appropriations can't be conditional, in fact I think they use the language "as needed".

PS. Mark Warner has introduced S.198 - A bill to provide for continuing appropriations in the event of a lapse in appropriations under the normal appropriations process, other than for the legislative branch and the Executive Office of the President.
No Bill Text is available on Congress.gov but is available here: https://www.scribd.com/document/398006535/Stop-the-Shutdowns-Transferring-Unnecessary-Pain-and-Inflicting-Damage-In-The-Coming-Years-Act

PSS the bills title there makes the acronym Stop Stupidity..

Answer (score 0):

There is no constitutional mechanism by which Congress can be forced to make any law whatsoever. The only recourse for a "do-nothing" Congress is to vote them out of office at the end of their terms.

If memory serves, the only thing that could be readily construed as a way around this is the clear stipulation that the compensation to certain officials cannot be changed (in the case of the President) or reduced (in the case of Congress); any failure to pass a law paying these fellows would probably wind up in the Supreme Court, who would at the very least rule that the government must cut those specific checks.

It is not impossible that one of the more rationalization-prone judges in the US federal court system would rule that the failure to make other payments is a violation of some person's rights. That would probably wind up in the Supreme Court's lap, too.

Comment: A failure to pass a law specifying the compensation of the president or congress would mean that the level of their compensation would remain unchanged, not that they would go unpaid.